# Dynamic UI changes using Nodejs Backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, frontend, ejs

I am beginner to Nodejs. I want to create a UI where there is a text box in the bottom and on typing input there, the UI elemts dynamically change. For example, if I type car, the image of the car appears which is a pre defined set of interaction. I tried using ejs on my own with no success.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// set up session cookies


// create home route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home', {item:text (typed text will come here)});
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('app now listening for requests on port 3000');
});
```

My home.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>Hello <%= item %></h1>
    <a href="http://www.google/com">Link</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no text box in your html - where are you planning on adding that? Also, you want the `app.get('/',...` to be called each time you type a letter, or only after you click a button? This is a very open-ended question

Comment: Text Box can come any where, preferably at bottom. If I type, Hi, the body must show, you typed "Hi" and so on. I tried with app.get however, I dont think its a good idea